# How to convert FIRDataSnapshot in array of dictionaries? Swift 3

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I have created 'struct FireBaseData' which enables me to retrieve data from Firebase. I would like to convert the data into an array of dictionaries and then output the content to Desktop in a .txt file.

How can I convert `self.bookingInfo` to an array of dictionaries?

```
 func startObservingDB() {

 dbRef.child(FullData.uid!).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in

        // an instance of FireBaseData holding all bookings under currentUid
        var newBookingInfo = [FireBaseData]()

 //iterate over all children under /FullData.uid! path
   for customer in snapshot.children {

      //the customer node starting with cus...
        let customerObject = customer as! FIRDataSnapshot

       //customer key
          self.customerKey = customerObject.key
             print("this is the Stripe customer that can be charged \(customerObject.key)")

 //now iterate over each booking which is located under customerObject in Firebase
     for booking in customerObject.children {



         // after each iteration through snapshot.children, create an instance of FireBaseData with  'booking' for the current iteration & assign it to bookingItem
            var bookingItem = FireBaseData(snapshot: booking as! FIRDataSnapshot)

        //assign key of the parent to each booking
                bookingItem.Key = self.customerKey

            // append the bookingItem after each iteration to newBookingInfo array
            newBookingInfo.append(bookingItem)

         } // end of  for booking in myCustomer

    } // end of  for customer in snapshot.children

        //assign newBookingInfo to global variable
         self.bookingInfo = newBookingInfo

 // sort the array in place so that the most recent date will appear first
 self.bookingInfo.sort(by: {(DateAndTimeObject_1,DateAndTimeObject_2) -> Bool in

    DateAndTimeObject_1.TimeStampDateAndTime > DateAndTimeObject_2.TimeStampDateAndTime
 })


   let arrayOfDictionary = self.bookingInfo.flatMap { $0.toAnyObject() as? [String:Any] }
    let stringSeparated = arrayOfDictionary.joined(separator: "-")
print("stringSeparated \(stringSeparated)")


          self.tableView.reloadData()
    }, withCancel: { (Error:Any) in
        print("Error firebase \(Error)")
    })

   } // end of startObservingDB()





 //Model to retrive data

import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase




struct FireBaseData {

// Create our Firebase Data model
// get arbitrary data

var FirebaseUserID:String!
var PaymentID:String!
var BookingAmount:String!
var BookingNumber:String!
var Key:String!
var PostCode:String!
var SelectedBathRow:Int!
var SelectedBedRow:Int!

var DateAndTime:String!
 var TimeStampDateAndTime:Int!
var TimeStampBookingSavedInDB:Int!

var BookingStatusClient:Bool!
var BookingStatusAdmin:Bool!
var BookingCompleted:Bool!


//used in RootController and RootController1 to determine if the booking has already been cancelled or not
var CostToCancelClient:String!
var CostToCancelAdmin:String!

var CostToRescheduleAdmin:String!
var CostToRescheduleClient:String!

var DoormanOption:String!
var EntryInstructions:String!
var NoteInstructions:String!


var FrequencyName:String!
var FrequecyAmount:Int!
var insideCabinets:Bool!
var insideFridge:Bool!
var insideOven:Bool!
var laundryWash:Bool!
var interiorWindows:Bool!

var SuppliesName:String!
var SuppliesAmount:Int!
var FullName:String!
var FlatNumber:String!
var StreetAddress:String!
var PhoneNumber:String!
var EmailAddress:String!

let Ref:FIRDatabaseReference?

init(BookingAmount:String,
     BookingNumber:String,
     PostCode:String,
     SelectedBathRow:Int,
SelectedBedRow:Int,
DateAndTime:String,
TimeStampDateAndTime:Int,

BookingStatusClient:Bool,
BookingStatusAdmin:Bool,
BookingCompleted:Bool,

FrequencyName:String,
FrequecyAmount:Int,
insideCabinets:Bool,
insideFridge:Bool,
insideOven:Bool,
laundryWash:Bool,
interiorWindows:Bool,
FullName:String,
SuppliesName:String,
SuppliesAmount:Int,
FlatNumber:String,
StreetAddress:String,
PhoneNumber:String,
EmailAddress:String,
Key:String = "") {

    self.BookingAmount = BookingAmount
    self.BookingNumber = BookingNumber
    self.Key = Key
    self.PostCode = PostCode
    self.SelectedBathRow = SelectedBathRow
    self.SelectedBedRow = SelectedBedRow
    self.DateAndTime = DateAndTime
    self.TimeStampDateAndTime = TimeStampDateAndTime

    self.BookingStatusClient = BookingStatusClient
    self.BookingStatusAdmin = BookingStatusAdmin
    self.BookingCompleted = BookingCompleted


    self.FrequencyName = FrequencyName
    self.FrequecyAmount = FrequecyAmount

    self.insideCabinets = insideCabinets
    self.insideFridge = insideFridge
    self.insideOven = insideOven
    self.laundryWash = laundryWash
    self.interiorWindows = interiorWindows

    self.FullName = FullName
    self.SuppliesName = SuppliesName
    self.SuppliesAmount = SuppliesAmount
    self.FlatNumber = FlatNumber

    self.StreetAddress = StreetAddress
    self.PhoneNumber = PhoneNumber
    self.EmailAddress = EmailAddress
    self.Ref = nil

}

// Content
// receive data from our firebase database

init(snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot){

    if let firebaseUserID = (snapshot.value! as? NSDictionary)?["FirebaseUserID"] as? String {
        FirebaseUserID = firebaseUserID
    }

  if let paymentID = (snapshot.value! as? NSDictionary)?["PaymentID"] as? String {
        PaymentID = paymentID
    }

    if let BookingAmountContent = (snapshot.value! as? NSDictionary)?["BookingAmount"] as? String {
        BookingAmount = BookingAmountContent
    }

    if let BookingNumberContent = (snapshot.value! as? NSDictionary)?["BookingNumber"] as? String {
        BookingNumber = BookingNumberContent
    }

    Key = snapshot.key
    Ref = snapshot.ref

    if let PostCodeContent = (snapshot.value! as? NSDictionary)?["PostCode"] as? String {
        PostCode = PostCodeContent
    }

    if let SelectedBathRowContent = (snapshot.value! as? NSDictionary)?["SelectedBathRow"] as? String {
        SelectedBathRow = Int(SelectedBathRowContent)
    }

    if let SelectedBedRowContent = (snapshot.value! as? NSDictionary)?["SelectedBedRow"] as? String {
        SelectedBedRow = Int(SelectedBedRowContent)
    }

    if let DateAndTimeContent = (snapshot.value! as? NSDictionary)?["DateAndTime"] as? String {
        DateAndTime = DateAndTimeContent
    }



    if let TimeStampDateAndTimeContent = (snapshot.value! as? NSDictionary)?["TimeStampDateAndTime"] as? String {
        TimeStampDateAndTime = Int(TimeStampDateAndTimeContent)
    }

    if let TimeStampBookingSavedInDBContent = (snapshot.value! as? NSDictionary)?["TimeStampBookingSavedInDB"] as? String {
    TimeStampBookingSavedInDB = Int(TimeStampBookingSavedInDBContent)
    }


    if let BookingStatusClientContent = (snapshot.value! as? NSDictionary)?["BookingStatusClient"] as? String{
        BookingStatusClient = Bool(BookingStatusClientContent)
    }



    if let BookingStatusAdminContent = (snapshot.value! as? NSDictionary)?["BookingStatusAdmin"] as? String {
        BookingStatusAdmin = Bool(BookingStatusAdminContent)
    }

    if let BookingCompletedContent = (snapshot.value! as? NSDictionary)?["BookingCompleted"] as? String {
        BookingCompleted = Bool(BookingCompletedContent)
    }



    if let costToCancelCient = (snapshot.value! as? NSDictionary)?["CostToCancelClient"] as? String {
        CostToCancelClient = costToCancelCient
    }


    if let costToCancelAdmin = (snapshot.value! as? NSDictionary)?["CostToCancelAdmin"] as? String {
        CostToCancelAdmin  = costToCancelAdmin
    }


    if let costToRescheduleAdmin = (snapshot.value! as? NSDictionary)?["CostToRescheduleAdmin"] as? String {
        CostToRescheduleAdmin = costToRescheduleAdmin
    }

    if let costToRescheduleClient = (snapshot.value! as? NSDictionary)?["CostToRescheduleClient"] as? String {
        CostToRescheduleClient = costToRescheduleClient
    }






    if let doormanOption = (snapshot.value! as? NSDictionary)?["DoormanOption"] as? String {
        DoormanOption = doormanOption
    }

    if let entryInstructions = (snapshot.value! as? NSDictionary)?["EntryInstructions"] as? String {
        EntryInstructions = entryInstructions
    }

    if let noteInstructions = (snapshot.value! as? NSDictionary)?["NoteInstructions"] as? String {
        NoteInstructions = noteInstructions
    }



    if let FrequencyNameContent = (snapshot.value! as? NSDictionary)?["FrequencyName"] as? String {
        FrequencyName = FrequencyNameContent
    }

    if let FrequecyAmountContent = (snapshot.value! as? NSDictionary)?["FrequecyAmount"] as? String {
        FrequecyAmount = Int(FrequecyAmountContent)
    }

    if let insideCabinetsContent = (snapshot.value! as? NSDictionary)?["InsideCabinets"] as? String {
        insideCabinets = Bool(insideCabinetsContent)
    }

    if let insideFridgeContent = (snapshot.value! as? NSDictionary)?["InsideFridge"] as? String {
        insideFridge = Bool(insideFridgeContent)
    }

    if let insideOvenContent = (snapshot.value! as? NSDictionary)?["InsideOven"] as? String {
        insideOven = Bool(insideOvenContent)
    }

    if let laundryWashContent = (snapshot.value! as? NSDictionary)?["LaundryWash"] as? String {
        laundryWash = Bool(laundryWashContent)
    }

    if let interiorWindowsContent = (snapshot.value! as? NSDictionary)?["InteriorWindows"] as? String {
        interiorWindows = Bool(interiorWindowsContent)
    }


    if let FullNameContent = (snapshot.value! as? NSDictionary)?["FullName"] as? String {
        FullName = FullNameContent
    }

    if let SuppliesNameContent = (snapshot.value! as? NSDictionary)?["SuppliesName"] as? String {
        SuppliesName = SuppliesNameContent
    }

    if let SuppliesAmountContent = (snapshot.value! as? NSDictionary)?["SuppliesAmount"] as? String {
        SuppliesAmount = Int(SuppliesAmountContent)
    }

    if let FlatNumberContent = (snapshot.value! as? NSDictionary)?["FlatNumber"] as? String {
        FlatNumber = FlatNumberContent
    }

    if let StreetAddressContent = (snapshot.value! as? NSDictionary)?["StreetAddress"] as? String {
        StreetAddress = StreetAddressContent
    }

    if let PhoneNumberContent = (snapshot.value! as? NSDictionary)?["PhoneNumber"] as? String {
        PhoneNumber = PhoneNumberContent
    }

    if let EmailAddressContent = (snapshot.value! as? NSDictionary)?["EmailAddress"] as? String {
        EmailAddress = EmailAddressContent
    }
}



func toAnyObject() -> AnyObject {

    var someDict = [String : Any]()

    someDict["FirebaseUserID"] = self.FirebaseUserID as AnyObject?
    someDict["PaymentID"] = self.PaymentID as AnyObject?
    someDict["BookingAmount"] = self.BookingAmount as AnyObject?
    someDict["BookingNumber"] = self.BookingNumber as AnyObject?
    someDict["PostCode"] = self.PostCode as AnyObject?
    someDict["SelectedBathRow"] = self.SelectedBathRow as AnyObject?
    someDict["SelectedBedRow"] = self.SelectedBedRow as AnyObject?
    someDict["DateAndTime"] = self.DateAndTime as AnyObject?
    someDict["TimeStampDateAndTime"] = self.TimeStampDateAndTime as AnyObject?
    someDict["TimeStampBookingSavedInDB"] = self.TimeStampBookingSavedInDB as AnyObject?
    someDict["BookingStatusClient"] = self.BookingStatusClient as AnyObject?
    someDict["BookingStatusAdmin"] = self.BookingStatusAdmin as AnyObject?
    someDict["BookingCompleted"] = self.BookingCompleted as AnyObject?

    someDict["CostToCancelClient"] = self.CostToCancelClient as AnyObject?
    someDict["CostToCancelAdmin"] = self.CostToCancelAdmin as AnyObject?
    someDict["CostToRescheduleAdmin"] = self.CostToRescheduleAdmin as AnyObject?
    someDict["CostToRescheduleClient"] = self.CostToRescheduleClient as AnyObject?

    someDict["DoormanOption"] = self.DoormanOption as AnyObject?
    someDict["EntryInstructions"] = self.EntryInstructions as AnyObject?
    someDict["NoteInstructions"] = self.NoteInstructions as AnyObject?


    someDict["FrequencyName"] = self.FrequencyName as AnyObject?
    someDict["FrequecyAmount"] = self.FrequecyAmount as AnyObject?
    someDict["insideCabinets"] = self.insideCabinets ? "true" : "false"
    someDict["insideFridge"] = self.insideFridge ? "true" : "false"
    someDict["insideOven"] = self.insideOven ? "true" : "false"
    someDict["laundryWash"] = self.laundryWash ? "true" : "false"
    someDict["interiorWindows"] = self.interiorWindows ? "true" : false
    someDict["FullName"] = self.FullName as AnyObject?
    someDict["SuppliesName"] = self.SuppliesName as AnyObject?
    someDict["SuppliesAmount"] = self.SuppliesAmount as AnyObject?
    someDict["FlatNumber"] = self.FlatNumber as AnyObject?
    someDict["StreetAddress"] = self.StreetAddress as AnyObject?
    someDict["PhoneNumber"] = self.PhoneNumber as AnyObject?
    someDict["EmailAddress"] = self.EmailAddress as AnyObject?

    return someDict as AnyObject

 }
}


Desired Output as per Nirav request

EmailAddress": johnmm@gmail.com,
"PhoneNumber": 07476953923,
```

"PaymentID": ch_1ARd6yLCZ34Ur7XG4wAqaH9H,
   "BookingAmount": 27

```
 EmailAddress": Chris@gmail.com,
 "PhoneNumber": 07476953923,
 "PaymentID": ch_1ARd6yLCZ34Ur7XG4wAqaH9H,
 "BookingAmount": 27


  EmailAddress": Mike@gmail.com,
  "PhoneNumber": 07476953923,
  "PaymentID": ch_1ARd6yLCZ34Ur7XG4wAqaH9H,
  "BookingAmount": 27
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to just use `toAnyObject()` method to get the dictionary object from your `FireBaseData` like this.

```
let arrayOfDictionary = self.bookingInfo.flatMap { $0.toAnyObject() as? [String:Any] }
```

You will get your desired result in `arrayOfDictionary` it is type of `[[String:Any]]`

Comment: It's working, but there is one issue, when I call `toAnyObject()` function as you suggested above, the Boolean values in `arrayOfDictionary` show as Int with 1  for true and 0 for false, rather than true and false. Given my initial model, how would I got about getting the result in String values for Bool values.

Comment: I was trying to output `arrayOfDictionary` content to a .txt file to Desktop that's why I needed to have String instead of Bool for those values

Comment: @bibscy Okay then what you can do is make one more method like this as of you cannot change this one because you are using this one with Firebase and after that when you set boolean value with key set it like this way.  `someDict["insideOven"] = self.insideOven  ? "true" : "false"`

Comment: I want to order the dictionaries inside of the array with one break between them so that I can output them nicely on Desktop in .txt file, but I get error: Argument passed to call that takes no arguments. `    let stringSeparated = arrayOfDictionary.joined(separator: "-")`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146635/discussion-between-bibscy-and-nirav-d).

Comment: at the bottom of my original question you will find the desired output.

Comment: @bibscy Why you want `//` at the beginning of all key, you cannot make response like that directly using joined you must go for for loop or some map closure, This is completely new question may be you need to ask new question here so some one else helps you.

Comment: I don't want '//' at the beginning, it was just the sign of commenting out the lines

Comment: How you will differentiate 2 objects in this as of all keys are in new line

Comment: I guess the logic should be like this. Each key:value pair in the array should be displayed on a new line. Whenever `SuppliesName` key appears, enter a new line.   This is the model with all vars   https://gist.github.com/bibscy/6414d35f10632e3d416726786eccc379

Comment: @bibscy You need to remember one thing that dictionary don't have any order